# permutations/combinations with repeated symbols

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

I've been learning some about counting and basic combinatorics. But some scenarios were not explained in my class...

**Example problem:** You are given 6 tiles. 1 is labeled "1", 2 are labeled "2", and 3 are labeled "3".

**Problem 1:** How many different ways can you arrange groups of three tiles (order matters)?

**Answer 1: 19**, {1,2,2} {1,2,3} {1,3,2} {1,3,3} {2,1,2} {2,1,3} {2,2,1} {2,2,3} {2,3,1} {2,3,2} {2,3,3} {3,1,2} {3,1,3} {3,2,1} {3,2,2} {3,2,3} {3,3,1} {3,3,2} {3,3,3}.

**Question 1:** You can't use the normal $\frac{5!}{\left(5-3\right)!}$ because you have repeated symbols. And you can't divide by the factorials of repeated symbols $\frac{6!}{\left(6-3\right)!\cdot3!\cdot2!}$ like you can when n = k and you make different arrangements of all n of symbols $\frac{n!}{\prod_{i=1}^mn_i}$. What formula would be used to find the answer to a more complex version of this problem?

**Problem 2:** How many different ways can you make groups of three tiles (order doesn't matter)?

**Answer 2: 6**, {1,2,2} {1,2,3} {1,3,3} {2,2,3} {2,3,3} {3,3,3}.

**Question 2:** You can't use the normal $\frac{n!}{\left(n-k\right)!\cdot k!}$ because you have repeated symbols. What formula would be used to find the answer to a more complex version of this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure this is the best method, but the way I would actually solve such a set of questions would be the following:

Use generating function methods for the second question.
The explicit collection of submultisets of the six tiles is given by the terms of $(1+x)(1+y+y^2)(1+z+z^2+z^3)$ (the $x$ terms correspond to tile 1, $y$ terms to copies of tile 2, and $z$ terms to copies of tile 3), and the numbers of submultisets of a given size are given ignoring the labels of the tiles and just multiplying the polynomials 
$$(1+x)(1+x+x^2)(1+x+x^2+x^3)=(1+2x+2x^2+x^3)(1+x+x^2+x^3)$$
$$= 1+(1+2)x+(1+2+2)x^2+(1+2+2+1)x^3+(2+2+1)x^4+(2+1)x^5+x^6$$
$$=1+3x+5x^2+6x^3+5x^4+3x^5+x^6.$$
Looking at the coefficient of $x^3$ in the product tells us that there are 6 submultisets.

Now the question of ordered triples drawn from the multiset is a little more difficult. I think I'd work out the explicit submultisets of size 3 first. I.e. solve question 2, then compute the number of ways to order each submultiset. There are a couple algorithmic methods to compute the submultisets of size 3. The first would be to multiply out the polynomials $(1+x)(1+y+y^2)(1+z+z^2+z^3)$ and compute the degree 3 terms. The others are essentially equivalent, but drop the mention of polynomials, and I find the polynomials are a helpful computational aide.

Now because I only want the degree three terms, I'll only compute those.
We have $$[(1+x)(1+y+y^2)(1+z+z^2+z^3)]_3$$
$$=1[(1+y+y^2)(1+z+z^2+z^3)]_3 + x[(1+y+y^2)(1+z+z^2+z^3)]_2$$
$$=1(z^3+yz^2+y^2z) + x(z^2+yz+y^2)$$
$$=z^3+yz^2+y^2z+xz^2+xyz+xy^2,$$
corresponding to submultisets
$\newcommand{\multset}[1]{\{\{{#1}\}\}}\multset{3,3,3},\multset{2,3,3},\multset{2,2,3},\multset{1,3,3},\multset{1,2,3},$ and $\multset{1,2,2}$.

Now we can work out how many ways there are to order each multiset in the usual manner: the ways to order a multiset of the form $\multset{a,a,a}$ is $3!/3!=1$, $\multset{a,a,b}=3!/2!=3$, and $\multset{a,b,c}=3!=6$. Thus summing the number of ways to order each of our multisets, we get $1+3+3+3+6+3 = 19$ different ordered triples drawn from our multiset.

Comment: That seems to work... I'm fairly nieve here, but do you know of a way to accomplish this mathematically instead of algorithmically?

Comment: @Elliot Trilling, I do not know of a simple mathematical formula in either case, so I settle for an algorithm, which at least will let me solve any instance of this problem in a unified way (even if it may not be very fast).

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to find a new formula every time you encounter a new counting problem! Counting problems have many variations so it's better if you know **how** to count rather than knowing the formula. For example, formulas for combinations and permutations are essentially coming from [Rule of Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product), where you give yourself a procedure to construct the objects that you want to count.

Thus, when facing a counting problem, ask yourself a question:

> How do you construct the objects?

Let's take an example as your first problem. Your objects can be divided
into three main cases:

Case $1$: If all three tiles have different labels, i.e. your set contains $1,2,3$ so this is a permutation problem which gives the answer of $3!=6$.

Case $2$: If two of the three tiles have same label. Such tile can either be $3$ or $2$ so there are two ways to choose such tile. After choosing a tile to appear $2$ times, we need to choose the remaining tile with different label. There are $2$ ways to do this. After that, we need to order the three tiles. Since two of the tiles have same label so there are $\frac{3!}{2!}$ permutation. This case gives $2 \cdot 2 \cdot \frac{3!}{2!}=12$.

Case $3$: All three tiles have same label. This is just $(3,3,3)$ so there is one tile in this case.

Summing up, you get $6+12+1=19$.

Answer (score 0):

Question 1:
This is the same as finding the number of permutations of the 'word' $ABBCCC$. Let us distinguish the same letters by subscripts so that we now have $A_1B_1B_2C_1C_2C_3$. The number of of permutations of this is just $6!$. But for each valid permutation, there are $2!3!$ repeats due to permutations of the $B_i$ and $C_i$. Therefore our answer is $\frac{6!}{2!3!}=60$.

Question 2:
My best guess is organized casework.

Comment: Note that the answer to question 1 is given by the OP and is 19, since it only asks for ordered triples of 3 symbols not ways to arrange all the tiles.

Answer (score 0):

**For the case where order does not matter.**

Suppose you have $x$, $y$, and $z$ objects A, B and C respectively. You are choosing $k$ tiles.

If $k-(y+z)>0$, then you need to pick at least $(k-(y+z))$ of object A. Otherwise, at least zero.

For $i$ of object A chosen, you must choose $(k-i)$ of objects B and C combined.

If $(k-i)-z>0$, then you need to pick at least $((k-i)-z)$ of object B. Otherwise, at least zero.

For $j$ of object B chosen, you must choose $(k-(i+j))$ of object C.

In total, you have $i$ of object A, $j$ of object B, and $(k-(i+j))$ of object C.

If order does not matter, you permute the chosen $k$ objects and account for the identical objects.

$$\sum_{i=\max\{0,k-(y+z)\}}^{i=\min\{k,x\}}\sum_{j=\max\{0,(k-i)-z\}}^{i=\min\{k-i,y\}}\dfrac{k!}{i!j!(k-i-j)!}$$

---

**For the case where order matters**

We don't really have a formula for this. But an organized method is more crucial.

Check if any of $x,y,z$ is less than $k$. Those that are equal or more than $k$ is in *excess supply* and we don't worry about them. Those that is less than $k$ introduces cases.

For your case, let me rename some stuff. You have 1 A, 2 B's and 3 C's. The *limiting agents* are $A$ and $B$.

So we consider all pairs of $(a,b)$ such that $0\le a+b \le k$. For your case, we have
$$(0,0),(0,1),(0,2),(1,0),(1,1),(1,2)$$

\begin{array}{c|c}
(a,b) & \text{number of ways} \\
\hline
(0,0) &  \frac{3!}{3!}=1\\
(0,1) &  \frac{3!}{2!}=3\\
(0,2) &  \frac{3!}{2!}=3\\
(1,0) &  \frac{3!}{2!}=3 \\
(1,1) &  3!=6\\
(1,2) &  \frac{3!}{2!}=3\\
\end{array}

Total: 19 ways.

Of course you can derive a summation from this, **but** a generalized summation is not very worth deriving unless you have a specific context.